# DataGridTextColumn not displaying any data

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to create a datagrid with each column displaying from a collection I've created. But I just can't seem to get any data to appear in the DataGridTextColumn. So assume the below collection _sym has been populated with data.

C#

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            ObservableCollection<decimal> _sym = new ObservableCollection<decimal>();            
            public ObservableCollection<decimal> Sym { get { return _sym; } }

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Xaml

```
<Grid >       
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sym}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Am I missing something in my XAML?  Do I need to use another DataGrid[InsertTypeHere]Column? Have I not correctly specified the binding source, target, or path?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the Binding in a wrong place. It should be set for the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`. The context inside `DataGridTextColumn` should be always each item (in your case it's just a decimal number). The code should be like this:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Sym}" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Something" Binding="{Binding}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks. So what if I wanted to bind each column in the DataGrid to different object? Is that possible?

Comment: @user1181337 currently your data item is just a `decimal`. So there are not any properties to bind (you have only 1 option is bind the decimal itself to 1 column of the datagrid). So it depends on your data.